# Display popup on the SIM phone call

Tags: android, screen, system

SHOW POP UP ON THE PHONE CALL SCREEN wen a detected a sim call phone.

Is it possible to display a popup on the interface of a SIM phone call with a cross-platform without the need for an API?  In this situation l'm using a phone_state flutter package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.